# ffmpeg и динамическая трансляция файла в канал RTMP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp

Моя программа создает не диске видеофайл, который нужно транслировать в канал RTMP. Файл пишется в реальном времени и его нужно передавать тоже в реальном времени. Когда я использую вот такую вот команду

```
ffmpeg -re -i output.avi -c copy -f flv rtmp://localhost/stream/mystream
```

то ffmpeg передает файл только до того места, когда он был запущен. Другими словами, если на момент запуска ffmpeg файл имел размер 20 мегабайт, то передадутся только эти 20 мегабайт, а то, что в файл дописалось в процессе передачи этих 20 мегебайт, не передается. Можно ли как-то настроить ffmpeg чтобы он передавал данные в поток до тех пор, пока не дойдет до конца файла?

Comment: А почему нельзя сразу писать RTMP-поток или поток какого-нибудь иного формата? Кажется, что с файлом не должно работать, так как вы хотите.

Comment: @Iliaw495Nikitin, в итоге получилось так: sprintf(command, "ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s %dx%d -i pipe:0 -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -nostats -f flv %s 2> ./logs/ffmpeg.log", size.width, size.height, url.toStdString().c_str());

Comment: А можно ссылочку на код целиком?

Comment: @Iliaw495Nikitin, добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

Для интересующихся. rtmpworker.cpp:

```
#include "rtmpworker.h"
#include <QDebug>

RtmpWorker::RtmpWorker(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void RtmpWorker::setUrl(int cameraID)
{
    url = "rtmp://localhost/stream/" + QString::number(cameraID);
}

void RtmpWorker::setSize(int w, int h)
{
    size.width = w;
    size.height = h;
}

void RtmpWorker::startRtmp()
{
    char command[512];

    sprintf(command, "ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr24 -s %dx%d -i pipe:0 -codec:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset ultrafast -nostats -f flv %s 2> ./logs/ffmpeg.log", size.width, size.height, url.toStdString().c_str());

    qWarning() << "RTMP command = " << command;

    if (( pipe_fp = popen(command, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        perror("popen");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void RtmpWorker::stopRtmp()
{
    pclose(pipe_fp);
}

void RtmpWorker::writeRtmp(cv::Mat frame)
{
    cv::Size size = frame.size();

    int total = size.width * size.height * frame.channels();
    fwrite(frame.data, 1, total, pipe_fp);
}
```

rtmpworker.h:

```
#ifndef RTMPWORKER_H
#define RTMPWORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

class RtmpWorker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit RtmpWorker(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setUrl(int cameraID);
    void setSize(int w, int h);

signals:

public slots:
    void startRtmp();
    void stopRtmp();
    void writeRtmp(cv::Mat img);

private:
    FILE *pipe_fp;
    QString url;
    cv::Size size;
};

#endif // RTMPWORKER_H
```